# Can a nonresident alien claim the NY State Standard Deduction (2018)?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, non-resident, state-income-tax

Can a nonresident alien (Form 1040-NR-EZ) claim the NY State standard deduction or does he/she need to claim itemized deduction (like on the federal return)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a nonresident alien is able to claim either the NY Standard deduction for claim itemized deductions. From p.49 of [Instructions for Form IT-203](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/it/it203i.pdf) (Nonresident and Part-Year Resident Income Tax Return) for 2018:

> Also, if you filed federal Form 1040NR you should claim the New York
>   deduction (itemized or standard) that is more advantageous to you.